# what constitutes a 24 hour period for ACH transfers?

Tags: money-transfer, ach

My bank limits me to a 50K ACH transfer in a day. Is a day 24 hours from the time I scheduled the transfer? Or from the time of the scheduled delivery?

Comment: Possibly only they would know for sure, so ask them. My guess from "_in a day_" would be midnight to midnight (or, probably, the "working hours" within those 24) and would be talking about initiating transfer(s).

Comment: Have you called them? My bank has something similar and it's per business day. For example, I can make an ACH transfer for the max amount at 4pm (before the bank closes) on a Monday, and then make another max transfer at 8am on a Tuesday.